# Integration by substitution in $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with Jacobian method proof

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I've searched everywhere on Google for a somewhat formal proof for the [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) -- a.k.a $u$-substitution or change of variables -- in double integral with the Jacobian determinant method but I can't find any. Anyone knows any sources for the proof?

In case if the theorem is not familiar it goes something like:

$$
\int\int_R f(x)d^2x=\int\int_Tf(G(u)) |\det DG|\, d^2u
$$

Comment: You may have a look at these [lecture notes](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_2200%3A_Calculus_for_Scientists_II/7%3A__Multiple_Integration/7.7%3A_Change_of_Variables_in_Multiple_Integrals)